# Add null character to string in python

Tags: python

I have list as:

```
['t','e','s','t','s','t','r','i','n','g']
```

How to add null character after each string `t`, `e`, `s`, `t`, `s`, `t`, `r`, `i`, `n`, `g`?

Comment: Why do you need to add the null character?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

List comprehension.

```
[c + '\0' for c in S]
```

But it smells like you want UTF-16LE instead.

```
u'teststring'.encode('utf-16le')
```

Comment: Why use u character in first of string ?

Comment: that's all what I want to know

Comment: `u` indicates that the string is Unicode, e.g., `u'teléfono'`

Comment: For those reading and still unsure of the reason there is a 'u' prefix: This prefix is indeed useless in Python 3 as all strings are manipulated in Unicode UTF-8 format by default, but could be used on 2.7 to force UTF--8 format, the default being Ascii (or at least some monobyte code).